# Using prune in find when searching for a specific name

Tags: linux, find

All the examples I read using find and -prune never seem to have the find looking for a specific filename. Let' say I want to do a search from root looking for any files on the system named "abc", I'd usually use:

```
find / -name "abc"
```

But now I want the same search, but I don't want to include any searches through /mnt or /tmp. How can I use prune in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
find / \( -path /mnt -o -path /tmp \) -prune -o -name "abc"
```